# How to omit to assoc array to consume items in PHP?

Tags: php

I am writing a function that converts MySQL query result into a HTML table. The problem is that first `foreach` renders multiple `<th>` based on first row of the result and "consumes" it from the array. Here's code of the function:

```
function generate_table($array, $caption = "") {
    $table = '<table>';

    if($caption) {
        $table .= "<caption>$caption</caption>";
    }

    $table .= "<thead><tr>";
    //The problem
    foreach($array->fetch_assoc() as $key => $value) {
        $table .= "<th>$key</th>";
    }
    $table .= "</thead></tr>";

    while($row = $array->fetch_assoc()) {
        $table .= "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $key => $value){
            $table .= "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        $table .= "</tr>";
    }

    $table .= '</table>';
    return $table;
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You can try $array->data_seek(0); after the first foreach.

Comment: Works! Thanks for help. I thought that, from the array elements are deleted, I had no idea there is a "data seeker" which points to current iteration.

Comment: You can change your `while()` to a `do...while()` loop so that you fetch the next record at the end of the loop.

Comment: @Inver Great, I put my commet as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this after the first foreach:

```
$array->data_seek(0);
```

That way you move result pointer to the beggining again.